# JHipster - Spring. Oauth2 resource server configuration. Create resource server

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, jhipster

When using simple spring boot configuration with normal spring parent in pom.xml I have no problem configuring oauth2 resource server.

However with JHipster dependency management by no means i can configure it.
I was trying to do it just by adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>[spring version]</version>
</dependency>
```

or by using some older configuration with other dependencies like here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server.html
And normally it works, but with JHipster I get @EnableResourceServer annotation, but I dont have in IntelliJ `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver` property. So I cant configure by what server should the token be validated, and I dont have `.oauth2ResourceServer()` method in HttpSecurity http (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter). I don't understand why is this happening. How can I get these properties? Or maybe I can override it by custom configuration somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster is configured to be a resource server by default, so you don't need to add any additional configuration.

From [SecurityConfiguration.java](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/config/SecurityConfiguration.java.ejs#L280):

```java
.oauth2ResourceServer()
    .jwt()
    .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
    .and()
.and()
    .oauth2Client();
```

Comment: Ohh, thanks. So shouldn't I be able to set spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri or jwk-set-uri in properties? Cause i cant. Is spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.issuer-uri or jwk-set-uri enough to authenticate the token?

Comment: Issuer URI should be enough. Spring Security can look up the JWK Set URI from this value.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i did it this way,
1-find the .yo-rc.json file of you project
2-open the file and find the tag "authenticationType", it should appear like "authenticationType": "jwt", change it to "authenticationType": "oauth2"
3 - run again the jhipster command in your project.

Here you have a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIRjgd_3sMQ